# Jetty can't start war file

Tags: java, spring, maven, jetty, war

I have a maven spring boot application and i successfully packaged a war file from Intellij. for a test i run jetty locally and put the war file in the webapps directory but i get this error:

> /hallo ---> o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@6c86e993{/hallo,[file:///C:/Users/ricardo/AppData/Local/Temp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-hallo.war-_hallo-any-3522993186615732718.dir/webapp/, jar:file:///C:/Users/ricardo/AppData/Local/Temp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-hallo.war-_hallo-any-3522993186615732718.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/jquery-3.1.1.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///C:/Users/ricardo/AppData/Local/Temp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-hallo.war-_hallo-any-3522993186615732718.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/bootstrap-3.3.7.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///C:/Users/ricardo/AppData/Local/Temp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-hallo.war-_hallo-any-3522993186615732718.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/bootstrap-3.3.7-1.jar!/META-INF/resources],UNAVAILABLE}{C:\Users\ricardo\Desktop\New folder\webapps\hallo.war} [failed]

The name is now hallo.war. Is there something wrong with my bootstrap jar? this is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demoshop</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>demoshop</name>
<description>tool</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.22</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-route53</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>   
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.7-1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.10</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

If you need more information i can provide it.

**UPDATE** 14-03: i have a error while starting the war file:

> 2017-03-14 12:05:59.772  INFO 6184 --- [      Scanner-0] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$344f3674] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
>   2017-03-14 10:03:51.288  INFO 4468 --- [           main]
>   o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet:
>   'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
>
> 2017-03-14 10:03:51.291  INFO 4468 --- [
>   main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter:
>   'errorPageFilter' to: [/*]
>
> 2017-03-14 10:03:51.292  INFO 4468 --- [
>   main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter:
>   'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*] 
>   2017-03-14 10:03:51.292  INFO 4468
>   --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
>
> 2017-03-14 10:03:51.292  INFO 4468 --- [           main]
>   o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter:
>   'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*] 2017-03-14 10:03:51.293  INFO 4468
>   --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
>
> 2017-03-14 10:03:51.402  WARN 4468 --- [           main]
>   ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered
>   during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration':
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method
>   'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.juli.logging.Log:
>   Provider org.eclipse.jetty.apache.jsp.JuliLog not a subtype
>
> 2017-03-14 10:03:51.411  INFO 4468 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer :

UPADTE POM.xml:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.7-1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.10</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
            <version>0.30</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

[image]

Comment: * i successfully packaged a war file from Intellij.* how did you create the war exactly? You should use maven and not the export from IntelliJ.

Comment: i used them both so from the command line mvn and in IntelliJ but both have the same result. command: mvn compile package war:war

Comment: There should be more logs indicating why it failed, an exception, or a message.

Comment: i put a edit above

Comment: you should only use `mvn compile package` that will get you a proper spring boot war. `war:war` will override the spring boot generated one with a plain war.

Comment: i tried that but it has the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i have changed in my application to make a war file work with jetty:

The application class with the guide: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

And the help of many I included the following in my pom file:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <jetty.version>9.1.0.v20131115</jetty.version>
    <servlet-api.version>3.1.0</servlet-api.version>
</properties>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-juli</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.0.M17</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
        <version>0.30</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 2):

You can exclude default Tomcat Embedded from Jar like this

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Then you should include jetty

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

run application using **mvn spring-boot:run** 
Hope this helps.

Comment: Running it in intelij works fine only the jetty still has the same error in the update

Comment: You must "exclude" tomcat from your application war and then deploy war to webapps folder.   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

Comment: i can't set scope in an exclude, but it gives the same error if i put it in the pom file

Answer (score 1):

From Spring Boot Documentation - [Create a deployable war file](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html)

You need something like this, if you want run on application server

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: do i need to have a path to the database because it's a h2 database and i think the database will not be made in the war file?

Comment: maybe try using h2 in-memory mode

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to deploy a Spring Boot application if you are using web dependency, it will automatically embed Tomcat for you, plus all the dependencies. Use a jar packaging, and you can run it directly using java: java -jar yourapp.java

Comment: Only our company is using jetty and war files to deploy there applications, should i change the dependencies?

Comment: checkout section 85.1 here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file Maybe you missed a step.

Comment: ok i tried that but he does not like the bootstrap and jquery dependencies

Comment: i did this and that part is working now i only have a error while starting the application.

Comment: @RicardoBuijsman can you show your pom.xml (the dependencies section)

Comment: The error sounds familiar. Can you try adding this exclusion to jetty dependency: `<exclusions> <exclusion> <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId> <artifactId>apache-jsp</artifactId> </exclusion> </exclusions>`

Comment: i placed it in and it gives me the same error, i just place it in the default jetty webapps at the moment.